# Proper Use of the Offset Function

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have the following formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(OFFSET($B$2,1,0),$A3,1),VLOOKUP(OFFSET($B$2,1,0),'Keyword list'!B2:E316533,2,FALSE),""),"n/a")
```

which looks up a value associated with a word if the word is found and otherwise returns "n/a".  I have included the OFFSET() function with the hope of making it so that when I move the formula to another column, say from column B to column C, the reference is not still $B$2, and not C2, but B3.  Effectively I am trying to make it so that when the formula is dragged across the reference row changes instead of the column, and when I drag down the reference remains fixed at $B$2, $B$3 and so on.  Is it possible to use the offset function to do this?  Is there a clear mistake I've made in trying to apply it to the above formula?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe try the following?

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(OFFSET($B$2,COLUMNS($A:A)-1,0),$A3,1),
 VLOOKUP(OFFSET($B$2,COLUMNS($A:A)-1,0),'Keyword list'!$B$2:$E$31,2,FALSE),""),
 "n/a")
```

I made a [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dGY4UVNMSGR5bHJnOFZ2cG8wVXBMd2c&usp=sharing) so that you can try to drag the formula across.

The limitation of that formula is that it will rely on the column of the formula, and it cannot be dragged towards the left in Excel, since that will cause the reference `COLUMNS($A:A)` to go `COLUMNS(#REF!)`. It can be put in any column then dragged to the right.

Comment: Thanks, after some troubleshooting it works quite well.  The only thing I'm trying to fix up is why it seems to check one row below the row the formula is written in.  Is there a way for it to check strictly across?

Comment: @Stopwatch It's because of relative addresses... Could you tell where is your actual data? The formula is made to be draggable, which means certain references are made to vary depending on the formula's position, and if you insert it in the wrong initial cell, it messes up :(

Comment: Hi Jerry, I was about to comment that I realized that as well.  It was because of a mistake in the initial formula I posted.  After changing from $A3 to $A2 everything is in good order!

Comment: I upvoted your answer earlier, but I'm curious why you say it can't be put in Column A.

Comment: @DougGlancy Oops, no you're right. It's just that once put in another column, it shouldn't be dragged towards the left in Excel because the `COLUMNS()` range turns into `#REF!`. That's the actual reason and I messed that part up in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but I think it does what you want, i.e., shift the reference down one row, for each column you drag to the right. It uses the COLUMNS function anchored at B in one half and relative in another:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(OFFSET($B$2,COLUMNS($B:B),1),$A3,1),VLOOKUP(OFFSET($B$2,COLUMNS($B:B),1),'Keyword list'!B2:E316533,2,FALSE),""),"n/a")
```

Comment: I just tried it out but unfortunately the row seems to stay fixed.

Comment: Hm, not sure why. This looks pretty much like what Jerry suggested, except his initial offset would be 0, mine would be 1.

Comment: I'm not sure why either.  Initially Jerry's didn't work until I realized my VLOOKUP range was wrong, but I'll keep troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with using INDIRECT to build a reference out of a computed string.

```
INDIRECT("B"&(2+COLUMN(<current cell>)-COLUMN($B$1)))
```

This way your reference gets calculated dependent from the offset to column B:

In cell D2 the referenced cell is `"B"&(2+COLUMN(D2)-COLUMN($B$1)) = "B"&(2+4-2) = "B4"`
In cell D3 the reference does not change, as only columns are taken into account.

Same for cell E2: `"B"&(2+COLUMN(E2)-COLUMN($B$1)) = "B"&(2+5-2) = "B5"`

If your calculation is that fixed, you could even only do with COLUMN(E2) as 2 and COLUMN(B1) cancel each other out: `INDIRECT("B"&COLUMN(<current cell>)))`

Comment: Thanks, would it look something like this then

=IFERROR(IF(FIND(INDIRECT("B"&(2+COLUMN(D8)-COLUMN($B$2))),$A8,1),VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("B"&(2+COLUMN(D8)-COLUMN($B$2))),'Keyword list'!$A$7:$D$316538,2,FALSE),""),"n/a")

I'm finding that this does not shift across expected either but I may be using it incorrectly.